# анимация в jqueryrotate

Tags: javascript, анимация

Не могу сделать плавное качание элемента `.test` (то есть он из начального положения (`0`) будет поворачиваться на `10` градусов по часовой стрелки, а потом возвращаться и так-же против часовой (`-15`) с помощью [jqueryrotate](http://jqueryrotate.com/).

Можно-ли это решить альтернативным способом?

Comment: Зачем альтернатива если вы уже нашли ротатор? смотрите examples и сделайте, непонимаю в чем проблема!?) либо приведите код ваш который не заработал, будем смотреть.

Comment: с помощью `CSS` можно спокойно сделать без всяких скриптов и библиотек

Comment: Я не спец в анимации, но вот как-то что-то примерно типа того можно сделать просто на `css` https://jsfiddle.net/qugqxLgj/